# ninja ripper shader into readable format (hlsl)

Tags: hlsl

How can I translate a shader that has been ripped into a readable format from asm (dxbc) to hlsl like this? I know the game and variables, I know the content too.

```
texld r3, r3, s0
    mul r4.xyz, r3, r3.w
    mul r4.xyz, r4, v0
    mul r3.xyz, r4, c1.x
    if_lt -r1.y, c26.z
      mov r5.x, c27.x
      mad r5.w, r1.x, r5.x, c0.x
      mad r5.xyz, r0.w, -c27.y, c27.z
      add r6, -r3, r5.zzzw
      cmp oC0, r6, r5, r3
    else
      cmp r3.xyz, -r1.y, r4, r3
      add r0.w, r1.y, r1.y
      mad r2.xyz, r2, -r0.w, v5
      mad r2.xyz, r0, c22.x, -r2
      mov r2.w, c2.x
      texldl r2, r2, s2
      mul r4.xyz, r2, r2
      mul r4.xyz, r4, c20
      mul r2.xyz, r2, r4
```

Tried everything on Github with the name "dxbc"; Nothing helped with solving this problem.